# Matlab subtract without rounding off negative number to zero

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays,

```
  X = uint8 ([ 255 0 75; 44 225 100]);
  Y = uint8 ([ 50 50 50; 50 50 50]);
```

When I perform X-Y, I get the result as

```
  205    0   25
    0  175   50
```

What I expect is

```
  205  -50   25
   -6  175   50
```

How to achieve this. Kindly help.

Comment: you're subtracting unsigned types

Comment: You can't *expect* negative values with `uint8` (unsigned integer)

Comment: use `int16` or some other class (`double`)
?

Comment: Everything that I want to say has already been said by all of these wonderful people.  My comment is purely for curiosity: Why is it important that your arrays be of an unsigned data type?  Unsigned data types cannot contain negative values by definition (hence **unsigned**).  Did you try casting your arrays to something that can handle negative values? (`'double', 'int8', 'int16'`...?)  Bear in mind that using signed data types will decrease your precision by half as one bit is required for the sign (i.e. `uint8`: [0,255] while `int8`: [-128,127]).

Comment: @rayryeng My hunch is that OP had the original data as `uint8` and is performing subtractions somewhere on the data. OP has given us the code for reproducibility, but made it more confusing in the end. BTW it makes us look crazy when everyone talks except OP.

Comment: Changed to int16. Everything is happy now :) Thank you so much guys. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint8` is can only contain values between 0 and 255 - it can't contain negative values. Use a signed data type (one without a `u` as its first letter).

Incidentally, do you have a good reason to specify the data type at all?